# After login, Server never gets to prompt

Tags: server

I am not fluent in Linux, but have been trying to expand my horizons, leveraging Ubuntu or derivatives to get more familiar with the OS.

I have run into an issue that has me grasping at straws.  I have a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Server install that has been working fine for months.  Out of the blue, after logging into the server, no prompt comes up...just a flashing cursor after the "state of the server" information comes up on screen.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKqfJ.jpg)

I don't know why the ~$ prompt is no longer coming up, and I haven't had any luck finding information via online searches.  There is only 1 account on the server, so there are no other accounts for me to try logging in with.  I have logged in via Single User mode, ensured all patches have been applied, verified hard drive space, but haven't been able to find anything that helps me resolve the situation.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be simply an empty prompt string (`$PS1`) but more often is due to a long-running or possibly recursive shell process (such as sourcing `.bashrc` from `.profile` and then sourcing `.profile` from `.bashrc`)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've compared the .profile and .bashrc against a working VM I have, and they are identical, yet 1 machine works as expected and the other does not. No commands work, pressing the 'Enter' key does nothing, and typing any commands does nothing.